# Using Flutter, what is the correct way to simulate clicks of a FlatButton?

Tags: dart, flutter

Please take a look at this code fragment:

```
final calculate = new FlatButton(
  child: new Text(_calculate),
  onPressed: _valid
      ? () {
          setState(() {
            model.inTemperature = stringToDouble(strTemperature);
            model.calculateOutTemperature();
          });
        }
      : null);
```

When the button is clicked, `setState()` is invoked with a lambda that does an assignment and a method invocation. Works perfectly. What I want to do is that, if a text field is submitted, that same `setState()` is executed.

The easiest way to achieve this would be something like `performClick()` on that button. Android knows this, for example. However, Flutter has no such method. So, what I do is this:

```
onSubmitted: (newValue) {
  setState(() {
    strTemperature = newValue.trim();
    calculate.onPressed();
  });
},
```

This works great, too. My Question is: is it ok to invoke the `onPressed()` callback on my own? Are there scenarios where my code might break?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe it would be better to create a method which can be called from both button and textfield (example below). I just think your implementation doesn't look that nice. The textfield should, in my opinion, not invoke the onPressed of a button. I don't have any scenario where that would break, though.

Something like this maybe?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  static void _setTemperature() {
    setState(() {
      model.inTemperature = stringToDouble(strTemperature);
      model.calculateOutTemperature();
    });
  }

  final calculate = new FlatButton(
    child: new Text(_calculate),
    onPressed: _valid ? () => _setTemperature() : null,
  );

  final textField = new TextField(
    controller: _controller,
    onSubmitted: (newValue) {
      setState(() {
        strTemperature = newValue.trim();
        _setTemperature();
      });
    },
  );
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('TestProject'),
      ),
      body: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          calculate,
          textField,
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Rainer, thanks. You are certainly right that my solution looks a little bit like a workaround. :-) Refactoring the few lines of shared code into a method and invoking it from both onPressed() and onSubmitted() is a clean and nice solution. Let's see if others come up with additional suggestions.

Comment: ...and is now the accepted answer. ;-) Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I want to call a common function `saveFn` on two different places.

1. By manually clicking a Button.
2. By pressing Enter key while typing inside a TextField, onSubmitted.

Note: First put a temporary bool value in the sample page as

```
bool simulating = false;
```

To call from a TextField & Simluate Button As Auto Clicking:

```
TxtField(
          text: className,
          key: newFieldKey,
          hintText: 'New Class Name',
          valid: validClass,
          onChanged: (String z) {
            setState(() => className = z);
          },
          onSubmitted: () {
            saveFn(isSimulation: true);
          },
        )
```

To call a real button:

```
Widget addButton() {
    return Button(
      key: Key(simulating.toString()),
      simulating: simulating,
      elevation: 0,
      isBig: true,
      icon: Icons.add,
      text: 'Add Class',
      processingText: 'Adding...',
      isOutlined: !validClass,
      buttonColor: validClass ? Colorz.green : Colors.grey,
      onPressed: saveFn,
    );
  }
```

The primary function to be called via 2 different places:

```
Future<void> saveFn({bool isSimulation = false}) async {
    if (isSimulation) {
       setState(() => simulating = true);
    }

    if (isSimulation) {
      setState(() => simulating = false);
    }
  }
```

Button widget:

```
class Button extends StatefulWidget {
  final dynamic icon;
  final dynamic onTaskCompletedIcon;
  final dynamic text;
  final String? processingText;
  final String? ontaskCompletedText;
  final Color? textColor;
  final double? radius;
  final Function onPressed;
  final Color buttonColor;
  final double? fontSize;
  final double iconSize;
  final int? maxLines;
  final double? width;
  final FontWeight? fontWeight;
  final bool upperCaseFirst;
  final bool isBig;
  final double elevation;
  final bool isOutlined;
  final bool isVoid;

  ///On some times, the [onPressed] function is called out of the button
  ///For example, pressing the [Enter] key from a [TextField],
  ///to simulate this button as pressed by hand, we can pass [simulating] as [true]
  final bool? simulating;
  const Button({
    Key? key,
    this.isBig = false,
    this.isOutlined = false,
    this.simulating,
    this.fontSize,
    this.iconSize = 20,
    this.icon,
    this.text,
    this.textColor,
    this.radius,
    this.onPressed = invalidAction,
    this.buttonColor = Colorz.primaryColor,
    this.maxLines,
    this.width,
    this.fontWeight,
    this.upperCaseFirst = false,
    this.processingText,
    this.ontaskCompletedText,
    this.onTaskCompletedIcon,
    this.elevation = 2.5,
    this.isVoid = false,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ButtonState createState() => _ButtonState();

  static Future<void> invalidAction() async {
    debugPrint('Invalid Action');
  }
}

class _ButtonState extends State<Button> {
  bool processing = false;
  bool processed = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
  if (widget.simulating != null) {
   processing = widget.simulating!;
  }
  super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedContainer(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 350),
      height: widget.isBig ? 65 : 52,
      width: widget.width,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
      // margin: widget.isBig && !kIsWeb ? const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12, vertical: 16) : null,
      child: finalButton(),
    );
  }

  Widget finalButton() {
    if (isIconButton) {
      return iconButton();
    } else {
      return normalButton();
    }
  }

  Widget iconButton() {
    if (widget.isOutlined) {
      return OutlinedButton.icon(
        icon: iconWidget(),
        style: outlinedButtonStyle,
        label: txtWidget(),
        onPressed: onPressed,
      );
    } else {
      return ElevatedButton.icon(
        icon: iconWidget(),
        style: textButtonStyle,
        label: txtWidget(),
        onPressed: onPressed,
      );
    }
  }

  Widget normalButton() {
    if (widget.isOutlined) {
      return OutlinedButton(
        style: outlinedButtonStyle,
        onPressed: onPressed,
        child: txtWidget(),
      );
    } else {
      return ElevatedButton(
        style: textButtonStyle,
        onPressed: onPressed,
        child: txtWidget(),
      );
    }
  }

  Widget txtWidget() {
    dynamic _finalText;
    if (processing) {
      _finalText = widget.processingText;
    }
    if (processed) {
      _finalText = widget.ontaskCompletedText;
    }
    _finalText ??= widget.text;

    return Txt(
      _finalText,
      fontSize: widget.isBig ? 18 : widget.fontSize,
      fontWeight: widget.fontWeight,
      maxlines: widget.maxLines ?? 1,
      useoverflow: true,
      color: _textColor,
      upperCaseFirst: widget.upperCaseFirst,
    );
  }

  Widget iconWidget() {
    Widget? child;
    final dynamic _icon = processed ? (widget.onTaskCompletedIcon ?? widget.icon) : widget.icon;
    if (_icon is IconData) {
      child = Icon(_icon, color: _textColor, size: widget.iconSize);
    }
    if (_icon is Widget) {
      child = _icon;
    }
    if (processing) {
      child =
          SizedBox(height: widget.isBig ? 35 : 32, child: Widgets.loader(valueColor: Colors.white));
    }
    return child!;
  }

  Future<void> onPressed() async {
    if (processing) {
      Widgets.showToast('Already processing...');
      return;
    } else {
      ///If the function is a not using [async] we don't need to process it to avoid [loading] indication
      if (widget.isVoid) {
        widget.onPressed();
        return;
      }
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          processing = true;
          processed = false;
        });
      }
      await Widgets.wait();
      try {
        await widget.onPressed();
      } catch (e) {
        Widgets.showToast('Error: $e');
      }
      if (mounted) {
        await Widgets.wait();
        if (mounted) {
          setState(() {
            processing = false;
            processed = true;
          });
        }
      }
    }
  }

  bool get isIconButton => widget.icon != null || processing == true;

  Color? get _textColor => widget.textColor;

  Color get _darkenButtonColor =>
      HSLColor.fromColor(widget.buttonColor).withLightness(0.45).toColor();

  Color get _buttonColor => processing ? _darkenButtonColor : widget.buttonColor;

  ButtonStyle get textButtonStyle => TextButton.styleFrom(
        backgroundColor: _buttonColor,
        shape: shape,
        shadowColor: widget.buttonColor,
        elevation: widget.elevation,
      );

  ButtonStyle get outlinedButtonStyle => OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
        shadowColor: _buttonColor,
        disabledForegroundColor: _buttonColor,
        foregroundColor: _buttonColor,
        shape: shape,
      );

  RoundedRectangleBorder get shape => RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(widget.radius ?? 6),
      );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, it is better to try to avoid "simulating gestures". In your case, it looks like you were able to do that.

However, for those people who are looking for a solution to truly simulate clicking, perhaps for testing, or other legit reasons, you can look into either using `GestureBinding` to dispatch gesture events, or calling `hitTest` on render boxes to get a list of acceptable gestures then invoking some of them. Both methods are valid, and you can find more details and examples in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54640608).