# How can I simulate a tap event on a Flutter widget?

Tags: dart, flutter

How can I simulate tap event on a Flutter widget?

For example, how do I simulate tapping on a Tabbar title? And more importantly, how can I find the widget in the first place? Please note that I don't want to call the relevant callbacks, nor testing widgets using Flutter test classes, but I'd like to simulate the tapping on widgets at runtime instead.

EDIT 1: (Please Note)
I DO NOT want to test a widget or call a method that is assigned to a GestureDetector.onTap or RaisedButton.onPressed etc...

Answer (score 12):

First, obtain a `RenderBox`. Then just call `hitTest` method. Any will do, as long as it's mounted in the tree.

To do so you'll have to use `BuildContext` through `context.findRenderObject()`.

```
BuildContext context;

final renderObj = context.findRenderObject();
if (renderObj is RenderBox) {
  final hitTestResult = HitTestResult();
  if (renderObj.hitTest(hitTestResult, position:  /* The offset where you want to "tap" */)) {
    // a descendant of `renderObj` got tapped
    print(hitTestResult.path);
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `HitTestResult` here?

Comment: HitTestResult is a flutter widget. It saves the results of the hitTest

Comment: Hi, shall I call things like `dispatchEvent`/`handleEvent`? I have heard that, a "real" tap will both call hitTest and dispatchEvent.

Answer (score 10):

Use `GestureBinding` to simulate a click event anywhere on the screen.

For example:

```
GestureBinding.instance.handlePointerEvent(
    PointerDownEvent(position: Offset(200, 300)),
)
```

[image: demo gif]

Full example:

```
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                backgroundColor: Colors.red[900],
              ),
              child: const SizedBox(
                width: 400,
                height: 400,
                child: Center(child: Text("I'm a big button.")),
              ),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                GestureBinding.instance
                    .handlePointerEvent(const PointerDownEvent(
                  position: Offset(200, 300),
                ));
                await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500));
                GestureBinding.instance
                    .handlePointerEvent(const PointerUpEvent(
                  position: Offset(200, 300),
                ));
              },
              child: const Text('Simulate Click'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can we target a specific widget with this?

Comment: @BroteenDas Yes, by attaching a `GlobalKey` to a widget, you can find its position on the screen by accessing its render object during run-time. With its position, you can then simulate clicking as usual.

Comment: Hi, I have try the example, and I put debugPrint inside big button onPressed, but when the pointer event is pressed, the debugPrint is not trigger, do you know why ?

Comment: is there something similar to simulate keyboard events?