# How to make auto click event at any position on Screen in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, native

I am trying make an **auto Clicker** app like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.truedevelopersstudio.automatictap.autoclicker). I am suffering with making click at anywhere in the screen(both in inside app and also when the app is in background means on other apps). I used a dragable widget to hover a little circle on the screen. I want to make the click event where that circle is.
Following is the code:

```
Positioned(
  top: height,
  left: width,
  child: Draggable(
    feedback: CirclePicture(),
    child: CirclePicture(),
    childWhenDragging: Container(),
    onDragEnd: (details) {
      setState(() {
        height = details.offset.dy;
        width = details.offset.dx;
      });
    },
  ),
)
```

This widget is in a stack, So I can easily move it inside the app. But I want to make click event the circle is in the app(also outside the app where only this circle will be visible).
I tried following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54640608/how-can-i-simulate-a-tap-event-on-a-flutter-widget) on stackoverFlow but It didn't worked.

If anybody knows how to make the click event(anywhere in the screen) without being touched on screen by user then kindly answer this question.