# How do I get the flutter to programatically click on specific coordinates?

Tags: flutter

I want to program an event that clicks on a coordinate

ex) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9Kf8.png)
button click! -> image x,y coordinate click!

```dart
 FlatButton(child: Text('TEST'), onPressed: () {}),
        FlatButton(
            child: Text('TEST2'),
            onPressed: () {
              print('click');
            }),
```

Comment: I wrote Stack Overflow for the first time, so please understand that the content is weird

Comment: Are you looking for integration testing? Or just to invoke clicks?

Comment: Actually, I wanted to see if the link was clicked when I put a link on the image and clicked the other button. I didn't think it was good because I asked questions while lacking a lot of knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want Button B to be clicked if Button A is clicked? In this case, simply also call the `onPress` callback for Button B:

```dart
void foo() {...}
...
void bar() {...}
      FlatButton(child: Text('TEST'), onPressed: () {foo(); bar();}),
        FlatButton(
            child: Text('TEST2'),
            onPressed: () {
              bar();
            }),
```

If you want to click on the specific coordinate, you can use `GestureBinding` as detailed here: [How can I simulate a tap event on a Flutter widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54640608/how-can-i-simulate-a-tap-event-on-a-flutter-widget/54641119#54641119)

Comment: Thank you. I'm sorry for answering so late. I'll do it using that method.