# React Native - trigger Touch at position programaticaly

Tags: react-native

I need to trigger a Touch event in React native programmatically anywhere on the screen.

Is there any way to achieve that?

Something like here in Flutter: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70873392/739927

Comment: do you mean something like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OZBjHv-Rlt0)

Answer (score 1):

it's possible to achieve it by using `react-native-gesture-handler`.

1. wrap the root layout with `<TapGestureHandler />` from `react-native-gesture-handler`
2. write a code that needs an access to coordinates with `onHandlerStateChange` handler.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { TapGestureHandler, State } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

const App = () => {

  const onHandlerStateChange = ({ nativeEvent }) => {
    if (nativeEvent.state === State.END) {
      const { x, y } = nativeEvent.absolutePosition;
      console.log(`coordinates: X: ${x}, Y: ${y}`);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TapGestureHandler onHandlerStateChange={onHandlerStateChange}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text>Press anywhere on the screen</Text>
        </View>
      </TapGestureHandler>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});

export default App;
```

it is also possible to achieve it using `<GestureDetector />`. this would be more elegant solution but needs more customization. [link to official document](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/manual-gestures/)